# mysqli returns nothing

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a mysql table like this

```
name    adults  children
single  1        0  
double  2        0  
suite   3        0
```

But I'm unable to retrieve the values of "adults" and "children" with this function

```
function getInfo($mysqli, $c, $query){

    // WARNING! THIS LINE IS NOT THE SQL QUERY BUT JUST AN ERROR LOG!
    error_log("query is: SELECT " . $query . " FROM categories WHERE `name` = " . $c);

    $mysqli->select_db("hotel");

    $sql = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT ? FROM categories WHERE `name` = ?
    LIMIT 0, 999999");

    $sql->bind_param('ss', $query, $c);



    $sql->bind_result($result);

    while ($sql->fetch())
        return($result);

}
```

error log shows the variables are correctly passed to the function:

```
[15-Apr-2013 19:36:10] SELECT adults FROM categories WHERE `name` = single
```

why is this function returning `NULL`?

Comment: Try quoting out the value you're passing to the query. Since you're using mysqli, you could also use a prepared statement instead, too.

Comment: I'm already using a prepared statement. I just use concatenation to error_log, not to prepare the query. Please read the question. Thanks!

Comment: You are quite correct - I did misread that. However - are you sure you can use bound parameters to specify the column names in your query?

Comment: I don't know. I don't see why not, but I'm not sure if this is allowed by mysqli. That's why I'm posting here...

Comment: You could try hard-coding in the word 'adults' to see if it returns something then - there should also be something in `$mysqli->error` if it fails, too.

Comment: yeah, I did that and it still didn't worked so I think the problem is somewhere else... Thanks for the suggestion btw!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss `$sql->execute();`

```
$sql->bind_param('ss', $query, $c);
$sql->execute();
$sql->bind_result($result);
```

Comment: it works now! But I'm not retrieving the value! I'm just getting the column name as a result... crazy!

Comment: @Saturnix Your `while ($sql->fetch()) return($result);` executes just once. Remove return operator from the loop.

Comment: yeah, that's right as the column "name" is unique, so there will only be 1 result... Still, this 1 result should not be the column name!

Comment: Of course, it should not... Don't you have 'adults' value in database due to some strange mistake?

Comment: nope, the database contents is as listed in the question. I've just concluded you CAN'T specify column name in mysqli prepared statement.